# Why does Django do cascading deletes on foreign keys?

Tags: python, sql, django, database

Django does a cascading delete on models with foreign keys as a default. That is, say you have a ForeignKey in A pointing to B, and you delete B, then A will be deleted as well.

[This is known and documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), but I haven't found any good rationale for the design decision around making it a default, given how unintuitive it seems. Does anyone know why it may be the case?

Comment: I believe it's because a object that depend on other can't exist if his dependency doesn't exist. It's a requirement relationship for the dependent object to exist. Take it from software, a program can't run if all of it's dependencies aren't there, right?

Comment: Why would you want to keep a related record there by default? Most of the time when you delete the parent record there is no need for the child.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**7 Years ago...**

a Ticket was open [#7539](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7539#no2)

**Where it began to be discussed.**

> years ago by benjaoming
>
> Someone requested a discussion... I just had an encounter with this,
>   and what I lacked was *knowing* what's going on with regards to
>   cascading deletion, because it's quite dangerous (you loose data!!)
>   and steals lots of time. Preventing it is simple, though. Overriding
>   the delete() method of a model and calling clear() on the related
>   model's foreign keys is simple, and it's a manual implementation, that
>   all programmers should be able to understand. But I can think of
>   another alternative: If null=True for the foreign key in question, why
>   not automatically use SET NULL when the related instance is deleted?
>   For me, this is even more "intuitive" than CASCADE. After all,
>   null=True is something that the programmer specifies and has to deal
>   with anywhere in the implementation, which is also why he doesn't need
>   cascading deletion of such a relation. Also, if on_delete is possible
>   to set in a key field, it would have to comply with the null option..
>   and together with the "intuition argument" that creates a 1:1
>   correspondence between the two options. And then the "logic argument":
>   Django handles its logic in Python code, not in the Database, which is
>   kept as a simple storage engine. The RESTRICT option is a validation
>   issue, and will probably be handled this way in most cases, so having
>   the database enforcing it, would be redundant. To enable it on
>   model-level could pave the way for some nice new automatic validation
>   in ModelForms, so I think it sounds like a nice feature. If all this
>   is implemented, I would suggest to remove the null option from key
>   fields and have it set according to on_delete.

**Years later, the matter was again discussed in the group.**

*Django developers (Contributions to Django itself)*
[changing the on_delete=CASCADE default](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/FJMoGgtYIX4)

**And then other tickets were created** [#21127](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21127) and [#21961](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961).

And we got here.
[ForeignKey and OneToOneField on_delete argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#foreignkey-and-onetoonefield-on-delete-argument)

> In order to increase awareness about cascading model deletion, the
>   on_delete argument of ForeignKey and OneToOneField will be required in
>   Django 2.0.
>
> Update models and existing migrations to explicitly set the argument.
>   Since the default is models.CASCADE, add on_delete=models.CASCADE to
>   all ForeignKey and OneToOneFields that don’t use a different option.
>   You can also pass it as the second positional argument if you don’t
>   care about compatibility with older versions of Django.

Comment: Thanks for all this context! Great to hear there are alternatives planned moving forward, and glad to hear I'm not alone in thinking it's silly ;-). I especially like the idea of an explicitly-set on_null argument.

Any idea about the original justification for it, or has that been lost to the winds?

Comment: Nice this cascading behaviour, but it would be even nicer if the python delete method of the child objects were also called, instead of only putting a SQL cascade constraint on the DB... Luckily we have pre_delete and post_delete signals! So pro tip: Never override the delete method on a Model, but use signals instead! (too bad it doesn't work the same with bulk create and bulk update... but that is another story)

Answer (score 6):

There is a fairly lengthy discussion on this [in this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21127). In Django 2.0 the `on_delete` argument [will be required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#foreignkey-and-onetoonefield-on-delete-argument) so the current default behaviour will no longer apply.